# How to get roll animation to work (roulette)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to do roll/roulette animation with no results.

```
<div class="roll">
    <img src="image.png" id="1" />
    <img src="image.png" id="2" />
    <img src="image.png" id="3" />
    <img src="image.png" id="4" />
    <img src="image.png" id="5" />
    <img src="image.png" id="6" />
    <img src="image.png" id="7" />
    etc ...
</div>
```

Images are inline so it would look like this

[image]
But instead of colors there will be images

[image]

I have array with players

```
var players = {
    1: "Player 1",
    2: "Player 2",
    3: "Player 3"
}
```

When the roll stops, the line in the middle will pick the winner and get the id.

When there's no more images to roll it will start over again

I'm not asking for source code. Just good instructions how do I get started with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done something similar and this is how I would go about it in steps:

**Step 1 - Build your carousel of images**

You need to ensure that you always have elements lined up far enough off screen that the user wont see any changes. Usually one or 2 extra off screen is enough. I don't know how you plan to build these images but if you provide some source code I can help you a little more.

**Step 2 - Make it move**

This is the easy part. Just move all of the elements left or right by x pixels and repeat while adding and removing elements as needed. Again, with code I can help more here.

**Step 3 - Pick the winner**

The way I see it, you can do this in one of 2 ways. One - Keep track of which element is overlapping with your line element each translation (step 2), OR - at the end simply look over all your elements to see which one overlaps the line.

**Short and easy version:**
While typing this I realize you could also pre-determine the winner, line up x images with the winner at the end, then add maybe 10-15 more after. Then just use a css transition on the parent element to move it just enough that the winner lines up with the blue bar. ***This is probably the easiest way to do it.***

---

**Example 1:**

Quick CSS easing example for either example:

```
transition: left 1s ease;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L2ofgs2k/ (I used jQuery to apply the style change but you can do the same with regular JS)

See here for more [help on CSS transitions.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: If I were to do this, I would probably use the second option I listed as it would be a lot less to keep track of and your animations are handled with CSS. (CSS `ease` will also take care of the sliding effect) and you know the winner before the carousel is even "spun"

Comment: Thank's helped alot.

Comment: No problem :) feel free to edit your answer with source code if you can't get it working and if you let me know I will extend my answer!

Comment: I was looking for something like this but automatic without buttons https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html Thank your for Razvan Alex

Comment: Can you show example about css `ease` x line movement

Comment: @Tonza added a quick JSFiddle

Comment: I appreciate it

Comment: @Tonza no problem. The effect is more exaggerated when it is a larger transition distance

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking to make a cs go roullete script. [This simple library](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) is exactly what you're looking for and many cs go sites use it as well. They provides demons and very good documentation. If you know a little bit of jquery, it's gonna be pretty simple.

Comment: Thank you. Never heard this berfore. I will look into it

Comment: sites like csgodouble, csgostrong use it and it's very simple to implement it ;)

Comment: You could set it up with jquery to roll automatically n times depending by the winner's id

Comment: Yes but I mean that it stop after every div for at least 0.5 sec

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can change the rolling time from 0.5 to 0.1 or somethin else